# how to clear values in listbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clear the values from list box and I used this code to clear

`$("#transfernumber").empty();`

It is not working any other options available.

```
<label>Send Coupon No.</label>
<span class="divider" style="width:auto">:</span>

<select value="" name="transfernumber" id="transfernumber">
   <option data-amount="data-amount">Select Coupon Number</option> 
</select>
```

after writing this code only it works

```
$("#transfernumber").multiselect('refresh');
```

Comment: what's your html structure..? and what do you mean by `clear values in listbox in jquery` ?

Comment: $("#transfernumber").val("");

Comment: `$('#transfernumber > option').remove();`

Comment: Please show your Html structure of a Jsfiddle

Comment: `.empty()` working for me. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PdNzP/)** . Do you have jQuery included? any console errors?

Comment: simply use 
$('#transfernumber > option').remove();

Comment: i used all the methods which is writen here and its working perfectly in fiddles but not in my code .

Answer (score 1):

your jquery

```
$('#transfernumber > option').remove();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/LSEnR/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#transfernumber option").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
$('#transfernumber')[0].options.length = 0;
```

or

```
$('#transfernumber').find('option').remove();
```

Comment: @NandhiniDevi: would be great if you can share the DOM as well

Comment: $("#transfernumber").html("");

Answer (score 0):

Just do following, and it will remove all options in select box

```
$("#transfernumber").html("");
```

Comment: @Nandhini Devi: you can also try out this answer and upvote if it is working for you. This would inspire new users on stackoverflow to get going.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#transfernumber").val('');// to clear the value
// to select the first option, as usual it may be "Select list"
$("#transfernumber option:first").prop('selected',true);
```

And if you want to remove all `options` then use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html)

```
$("#transfernumber").html('');// to remove all options
```